# Redirect to home when using Hamburger menu

Tags: android

How can redirect to MainActivity or a specific Fragment when I press the top left arrow?

So I started from here: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back#java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                // Handle the back button event
            }
        });
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);

        // The callback can be enabled or disabled here or in handleOnBackPressed()
    }
    ...
}
```

but OnBackPressedCallback and method getOnBackPressedDispatcher  does not exist. What I'm doing wrong here?

Update: 
In order to be able to import OnBackPressedCallback  you need to add to gradle dependecy 
    def activity_version = "1.1.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity:$activity_version"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
    OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Handle the back button event
        }
    };
    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);

    // The callback can be enabled or disabled here or in handleOnBackPressed()
}
...
```

}

So make sure you have gradle up to date, else it won't work.
PS: there is a ")" in the Google Code ... make sure you delete it!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this simply by adding your fragment to backstack and on MainActivity overirde on onBackPressed

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {     
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

and you can call this method from any fragment

```
(MainActivity)getActivity.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: I know how to redirect to a fragment. I just want when people are clicking the back left icon, instead of going to previous fragment to go to main fragment for example.